# How to catch exception in controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In my controller i need to test custom database connection and if it's bad return an error. The problem is that `catch` block doesn't work... I get an exception message which is globally defined in `app/start/global.php`.

```
try {
    DB::connection('test');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    dd('error');
}
```

Comment: what happens with this code ? "doesn't work" is too wide...

Comment: @Random as i said it doesn't work. When connection is bad it should show `error` message from `dd`, but it just throws original laravel exception

Comment: it may have an error_handler. maybe DB::connection throws an error (so no exception), and Laravel catches it to end it its own way... can you see what is the error handler ?

Comment: @Random `"type":"PDOException","message":"SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused",`

Comment: Do "catch (\Exception $e)" and it should work

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo why add a `\ `  ?

Comment: Did it help or not?  :)

Answer (score 3):

Laravel handles exceptions, no need for try/catch. You can write a custom exception inside \App\Exceptions and customise the contents of App\Exceptions\Handler.php to format the response of any individual exception to meet your needs.